# Linq select result with duplicating rows

Tags: c#, linq

My select returns joined data from db where for every object there are several attributes. For every attribute of the object I have a new row.
I use Entity Framework to retrieve the data.

```
var products = _ctx.ExecuteFunction<GetProducts_Result>("GetProducts");
```

GetProducts is a stored proc that returns following result.

```
Code    | Name | Term | Rate
--------+------+------+-----
111     | Foo  | 12   | 10
111     | Foo  | 24   | 12  
111     | Foo  | 36   | 16
222     | Boo  | 12   | 8
222     | Boo  | 24   | 9
```

How I can efficiently query data with linq and map to a class like

```
class Product
{
     int    Code
     string Name
     List<Term> terms;
}
```

Where Term is a class with parameters (Term, Rate)

Comment: I think there is too much data missing. how do you get the first result? By the way, if you wanted to get the data this way, why didn't you save the data in the database in that form?

Comment: Is Code+Name the primary key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var products = from p in _ctx.ExecuteFunction<GetProducts_Result>("GetProducts")
               group p by new {p.Code, p.Name} into g
               select new Product
               {
                   Code = g.Key.Code,
                   Name = g.Key.Name,
                   terms = g.Select(x => new Terms { 
                                            Term = x.Term, 
                                            Rate = x.Rate }).ToList()
               };
```